# I have a table for postcodes but I need to check the counts only for post codes that starts with EX and RG?

Tags: mysql

I have a table for postcodes but I need to check the counts only for certain postcodes that starts with EX and RG?

Comment: `where pcode like 'EX%' or pcode like 'RG%'` ?

Comment: Did you do your homework? This is SQL 101

Answer (score 0):

Your query should be more like this.

```
SELECT foo1, foo2 FROM tblPoastalCodes WHERE pcode LIKE '[EX]' AND '[RG]'
```